# Hey, How can I solve SyntaxError: D:\complaint_reactjs\node_modules\watchpack\lib\chokidar.js: 'return' outside of function (4:1) Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/watchpack/lib/chokidar.js
SyntaxError: D:\complaint_reactjs\node_modules\watchpack\lib\chokidar.js: 'return' outside of function (4:1)

```
  2 | try {
  3 |   module.exports = require("chokidar");
> 4 |   return;
    |   ^
  5 | } catch(e) {
  6 |   v3Err = e;
  7 | }
```

and this is the chokidar.js

```
var v3Err;
try {
    module.exports = require("chokidar");
    return;
} catch(e) {
    v3Err = e;
}

var v2Err;
try {
    module.exports = require("watchpack-chokidar2");
    return;
} catch(e) {
    v2Err = e;
}

throw new Error(
    "No version of chokidar is available. Tried chokidar@2 and chokidar@3.\n" +
    "You could try to manually install any chokidar version.\n" +
    "chokidar@3: " + v3Err + "\n" +
    "chokidar@2: " + v2Err + "\n"
)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please explain how you are getting this error

Comment: function somefunctionname(){
try {
module.exports = require("chokidar");
return;
 } catch(e) {
   v3Err = e;
 }
}
somefunctionname()


You can only return inside a function not outside of it

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial  I was coding reactjs project then I got this error

Comment: @dEBAM l I was coding reactjs project then I got this error

Comment: @AshwinRaoK I updated my question with chokidar.js file

Comment: i mean, why are you putting module.exports in a try catch. You can have multiple require, but should only have one module.exports in a single js file. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports